# How to configure OpenLDAP with SSL as proxy for Active Directory with LDIF method

Tags: debian, centos, ldap, openldap

EDITED: As it seems nobody seems to really know how OpenLDAP works (beside their developers), I finally dropped it in favor of GLAuth, which is quite easier to set up, with a simple configuration file. I managed to solve my problem in minutes. I understand that OpenLDAP perhaps is more powerful or have more capabilities, but to proxy an AD, using OpenLDAP is like use a sledgehammer to crack a nut, so, perhaps you want to avoid it.

On my company, we have an Active Directory to manage users, and many web services outside the office that we want to make their login system to be done via ldap. I want to publish the LDAP via SSL and make all those web services login against our AD, but I don't want to expose the AD not even via SSL, so I want to set up an OpenLDAP proxy to AD in our DMZ and connect to the AD in read-only mode. I'm not and LDAP expert at all, and when I set up other LDAP in the past I followed a few steps to have one running and then, managed them with Apache Directory Studio or LAM, I expected this to be quite easier to accomplish and well, it seems pretty more hard to accomplish than I expected.

I've been dealing with this for weeks now, and I couldn't find any way to accomplish it. Everyone says slapd.conf is deprecated, and must be not used anymore, and there are plenty of tutorials in how to configure OpenLDAP with SSL via LDIF, but I couldn't find any way to configure, via LDIF an **openldap with ssl being a proxy for AD**.

The only way I could find to configure LDAP as proxy for AD was on the samba site with this slapd.conf file

```
### Schema includes ###########################################################
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

## Module paths ##############################################################
modulepath              /usr/lib64/openldap/
moduleload              back_ldap
moduleload              rwm

# Main settings ###############################################################
pidfile                 /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile                /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

### Database definition (Proxy to AD) #########################################
database                ldap
readonly                yes
protocol-version        3
rebind-as-user
uri                     "ldap://{AD-Hostname/IP}:389"
suffix                  "{your Domain DN}"
overlay                 rwm
rwm-map                 attribute       uid     sAMAccountName

### Logging ###################################################################
loglevel                0
```

I also modified the `schemas/inetorgperson.schema`, and added this

```
################
#AD schema
################
attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
      NAME 'sAMAccountName'
      SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15' SINGLE-VALUE )
################
```

And finally, added the sAMAccountName attribute on `schemas/inetorgperson.ldif` by adding

```
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221 NAME 'sAMAccountName' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

and

```
olcObjectClasses: ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.2.2 NAME 'inetOrgPerson' DESC 'RFC2
798: Internet Organizational Person' SUP organizationalPerson STRUCTURAL MAY
( audio $ businessCategory $ carLicense $ departmentNumber $ displayName $ em
ployeeNumber $ employeeType $ givenName $ homePhone $ homePostalAddress $ ini
tials $ jpegPhoto $ labeledURI $ mail $ manager $ mobile $ o $ pager $ photo
$ roomNumber $ secretary $ uid $ userCertificate $ x500uniqueIdentifier $ pre
ferredLanguage $ userSMIMECertificate $ sAMAccountName $ userPKCS12i ) )
```

And it worked, but after deleting the directory `slapd.d` and recreating it with

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
```

(and apply proper ownership afterwards).

Obviously, when I did that, my previous configuration with LDIF -create a local database and set up SSL- got deleted, and since I used the slapd.conf and created the sladp.d directory, my ldap administrator account got deleted as well, and I cannot configure SSL again or add more databases.

So, I need to know how to mix it up all together: or a slapd.conf file example to set up a proxy for AD *and* have a manager user to modify the LDAP with future LDIF, or a LDIF example for configuring a proxy for AD.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Well, if someone stumbles upon this, I finally dropped openldap in favor of glauth, it can act as proxy for an AD transparently without any mapping, and it can serve via SSL just fine with a simple config file. I'd set up my AD proxy with SSL in just a few hours (now it would take like 5 minutes). My advise, if you don't need to serve thousands of ldap request per second, avoid openldap.

Comment: I'm doing nearly the exact same thing. Basically need to authenticate off of AD in a DMZ.
Can you share your glauth path, or perhaps a sample config file.
Of course with proprietary info redacted.